# How can the softmax distribution be used to detect out-of-distribution samples?

Tags: neural-networks, softmax

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02136.pdf) paper and it states that - "*In what follows we retrieve the maximum/predicted class probability from a softmax distribution and thereby detect whether an example is erroneously classified or out-of-distribution.*"

However, I don't see how they use the softmax distribution to detect OOD samples. In their description for Table 2, they have the following line: *"Table 2: Distinguishing in- and out-of-distribution test set data for image classification. CIFAR10/All is the same as CIFAR-10/(SUN, Gaussian)."*

My question is how do they distinguish between in and out-of-distribution samples?

Comment: The paper is very poorly written. There's some kind of hand-waving explanation at the start of section 3, involving ROC curves, but I'm not clear on the exact mechanics of the procedure. The code is available on Github; reviewing the code is probably the only way to figure out what they're doing.

Comment: Without reading the paper: it could be simple difference in probability like in distribution will have probability above a threshold.